# How to create URLs similar to Pastebin, Imgur, Youtube etc.?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm creating a site (with PHP & MySQL) that takes a user input, generates a random link, and uses that users input on the generated link to show content.

The nearest real-life example would be http://pastebin.com/ - you enter a text input on the homepage, it generates a random link (such as http://pastebin.com/2hf4Dtv7 and then the text you input is permanently displayed on that generated link.

I've been stuck on this problem for what seems like forever. I've managed to get different parts of the problem solved (I think), but I can't seem to get it to work altogether.

**Key facts**

- The user input needs to be available to use on the generated link
- A PHP file *run.php* is what I will use to display content / manipulate the user's input, so somehow needs to be available on the generated link (unless there's another way to do this).
- I have a MySQL database that currently has / stores 3 columns: *ID* (integer, which automatically increments), *userinput* (varchar, which is set to unique) and *pageurl* (varchar, which is also set to unique)
- The site is using WordPress, but that's not too important as I'm dealing with the PHP / htaccess file(s) directly.

**Things I've attempted / managed to do:**

- I can generate a random string for the url, via `<?php echo $randGen ?>`. This can be put into `<form action="<?php echo $randGen ?>" method="POST">` - This works in the sense that it will open a tab to *domain.com/xyz*, but that 404s & *run.php* isn't assigned to the generated link (I'm not sure if the input value is either).
- Tried both `POST` and `GET` methods in the form. The input data isn't sensitive, so it isn't a huge issue which is used.
- Read up on & attempted to use .htaccess rewrite rules / pretty urls, such as `RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ run.php?userinput=$1 [NC,L]`, as well as trying to use `[QSA]` & `&%{QUERY}` to keep the user input, but found myself to be way out of my depth.
- Attempted to covert the MySQL (auto-incrementing) ID to base64, but aren't sure where to run the PHP script to get it working & also don't understand how to append that random string to the URL, while still showing the users input.
- Watched numerous tutorials on how to create pastebin-esque sites / URL shortener sites, to see if I could get any relevant ideas from that - to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, `RewriteRule` is the way to go.

With this in your apache configuration:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ run.php?randurl=$1 [L]
```

This, in your html page:

```
<form action="/run.php" method="POST">
  Userinput: <input type="text" name="userinput">
```

You then just need to use the variables `$_GET['randurl']` and `$_POST['userinput']` in run.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['userinput'])) { // user adds a new input
  // insert into database (userinput, randurl) values ('".$_POST['userinput']."', '".$randGen."') 
  // redirect the user to the new short URL page:
  header('Location: domain.com/'.$randGen);
}
else if (isset($_GET['randurl'])) { // user wants to access the short URL
  // retrieve userinput from database:
  // select userinput from mydatabasename where randurl = 'domain.com/'.$_GET['randurl']
  $sql = "SELECT userinput FROM articles WHERE randurl = '".$_GET[randurl]."'";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result) {
    if ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
      // echo select result in the page
      echo($row['userinput']);
    }
    else
      echo("error: fetch_object");
    $result->close();
  }
  else
    echo("error: query");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a clear answer. I'm having a little difficulty understanding what to include inside the `if / else if` statement. So far I have the `userinput` and a random `pageurl` (in the form of *domain.com/xyz* being POST'ed from the form and inserted into the database. So in my database I have a row of values (e.g. `ID: 5, userInput: Hello!, pageurl: domain.com/abcxyz`). However, that random pageurl still 404s whenever I visit it & the form still redirects to `domain.com/run.php` instead of to the newly generated, shortened url.

Comment: When the user adds a new userinput, you will receive it in run.php with the variable `$_POST['userinput']`, thus, in the `if` statement, you should add the new entry in your database. When the user opens `domain.com/xyz`, he will in fact open `domain.com/run.php?pageurl=xyz`, so in the `else` statement, you should read the database and display the corresponding `userinput`...

Comment: Apologies for the slow response. I've attempted that but I always get an error when I try to create a database entry inside of the `if / else` statement. I'm not sure if you can notice any obvious errors I've made? https://jsfiddle.net/Pebbley/w52n15vo/

Comment: If you do not mention which error you get, it will be hard to help you...

Comment: It was just giving me an internal server error). However, that part is solved now (no longer getting that error). I've updated the code (entire PHP code here: https://jsfiddle.net/Pebbley/6o20x0v0/) and it is incredibly close to working now. It successfully redirects to a random URL when the form is submitted, however, it still 404s once it gets to that random URL. So I assume *run.php* nor the *userinput* is being assigned to that random url?

Comment: It seems like the `RewriteRule` did not match the short URL. Have you reloaded/restarted Apache after editing the Apache configuration files ? What is the complete URL for which you receive a 404 ?

Comment: You're completely right, the RewriteRule wasn't matching up, however, the url doesn't show up as `domain.com/run.php?pageurl=X` because it's using `POST` not `GET`. So when I submit the form (without redirecting) it goes to `domain.com/run.php`. The RewriteRule I've added is `RewriteRule ^/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ /run.php [NC,L]` (entire htaccess file - https://jsfiddle.net/Pebbley/npfky1o6/) - still 404s. I've closed and saved the files after changing.

Comment: So, when you type in your browser `domain.com/xyz` you get a 404. Maybe `mod_rewrite` is not installed on your web server, or `run.php` is not in the root folder of your web site. You have no problem browsing `domain.com/run.php`?

Comment: Yeah, it 404s whenever I visit `domain.com/xyz` however, I added `<h1>Hello World</h1>` to my run.php file and I can see it if I visit `domain.com/run.php`. I don't think it's an issue of `mod_rewrite` not being installed, as other Rewrite rules seem to work without issue.

Comment: Could you place this line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ run.php [L]` just after the `RewriteBase /` line in you htaccess file and try again to access `domain.com/xyz` to be sure ?

Comment: That made every page (including the homepage) into run.php (every page was displaying `<h1>Hello World</h1>` which I added to run.php).

Comment: Change now this line by `RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ run.php?pageurl=$1 [L]` and try again `domain.com/xyz` ?

Comment: This is so close. Submitting the form will take you to a random url that is running *run.php*. That page will show `Hello world` or anything I write in the *run.php* file. However, it won't display `<?php echo $_GET['userinput']?>` (but will add it to the database). If I add `<?php echo $_GET['randurl']?>` it will display the random code that's being used in the url (also be added to the database). `<?php echo $_GET['userinput']?>` did display up until that last RewriteRule was added. Sorry to be such a pain, I really appreciate all this help. Super valuable info.

Comment: There isn't any error messages or anything like that, so it seems strange I can't access the `userinput`. I wondered whether it might be because I haven't done anything with the `else if (isset($_POST['randurl']))` (entire code incase it's helpful: https://jsfiddle.net/Pebbley/munx03ch/)

Comment: You won't get anything in `$_GET['userinput']`, you have to get userinput from your database using `$_GET['randurl']` as I wrote in the comment of the `else` statement in my answer.

Comment: Oh right, so would I need to put all the code for the entire *run.php* (all functions, algorithms etc.) within those `if / else` statements? It's giving a strange error `Unknown column 'QVpbZ' in 'where clause'` where `QVpbZ` is the randomly generated code. After researching I tried surrounding it with quotes, also tried using `HAVING` statements etc. but none of that seems to work using `$sql = "SELECT userinput FROM articles WHERE randurl = $_GET[randurl]";`

Comment: Sorry, it was pseudo SQL code. In real SQL you would write: `$sql = "SELECT userinput FROM articles WHERE randurl = '".$_GET[randurl]."'"`. You can separate code in different functions/files later...

Comment: That got rid of the `Unknown column` error and instead just gives a general error `Error: SELECT userinput FROM mydatabasename WHERE randurl = 'twbl5'` (I'm not sure if it's helpful, but that's the php code: https://jsfiddle.net/Pebbley/rut7vsvk/1/)

Comment: You do not run `select` queries the same way you run `insert` ones. I have updated the answer to give you directions, but you should read php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php or other PHP/database manuals to handle this kind of operations.

Comment: Thanks for the resource! Even with that statement, I'm unfortunetly still unable to `echo $_GET['userinput']` or `echo $_POST['userinput']` or `echo $result` or `echo($row['userinput'])`, so I can't check if it's working correctly.

Comment: As I said earlier, do not try to print `$_GET['userinput']` or `$_POST['userinput']`, these variables do not exist when you access your short URL page `domain.com/xyz`. Instead, try to print to get more information on error when you select userinput from your database...